# Why does the method I have to reload the row in a table only reload once?

Tags: objective-c, ios, reloaddata

I've been working on this for hours, to no avail, I have a method that on viewWillAppear reloads the section of the table. However, after the first reload, the method doesn't seem to work anymore. I know this because I put an NSLog in the cellForIndex method. If it matters I am pushing and popping a navigation bar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"START TIME:%@", eSTime);
    NSLog(@"END TIME:%@", eEtime);
    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    reloadRows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: What does your cellForRowAtIndexPath method look like? When you say you put a log in it, does it not even get called?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this is because for some reason the view controller's container view only tells it that it appears once.

The view controller that you've placed this in has the responsibility to tell it when it will, and has appeared, and whether that was in an animated fashion.

If for some reason the view controller did not call this method correctly after the first appearance, the view controller will only ever once receive with -viewWillAppear: method call, and thus the reload will only happen that one time.

So the question becomes: how are you showing this view controller? Is it in a container that you made yourself, or in a UINavigationController, or something else?